# Char array assignment not working

Tags: c, pointers

The following code converts all lower case characters in a string to uppercase. However it is not replacing the lowercase character with the calculate uppercase character.

```
static char * strtoupper(char * string, int size)
{
char c;
for(int i = 0; i< size; i++)
{
    if(islower((int) (*string)) != 0)
    {
        c = (char) toupper(*string);
        *string = c;
    }
    ++string;
}
return string;
}
```

Comment: Why do you test for `islower()`? and `*string = toupper(*string);` sould be fine.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hint: what does `string` point to after incrementing it `size` times?

Comment: Probably wanted something closer to [**this**](http://pastebin.com/E9QMQXsd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the incremented pointer, you don't need to return anything, just modify the string in place

```
void strtoupper(char *string)
{
    while (*string != '\0') 
    {
        *string = toupper(*string); 
        ++string;
    }
}
```

and if you want to pass the length of the string, if for example it's not null terminated

```
void strtoupper(char *string, size_t size)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
        string[i] = toupper(string[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Apparently the desired goal to return a string pointer as-passed to the called function is not a requirement. One wonders why it was in the OP's code in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Take into account that your function returns a pointer after the n-th (that is size) element that in general case can be the terminating zero.

I would write the function the following way

```
static char * strtoupper( char *string, size_t size )
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        if( islower( ( unsigned char )string[i] ) )
        {
            string[i] = toupper( ( unsigned char )string[i] );
        }
    }

    return string;
}
```

Also you may not pass a string literal to the function as an argument because you may not modify string literals. Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behaviour of the program.

So for example this call of the function is invalid

```
strtoupper( "Hello", 5 );
```

But this is valid

```
char s[] = "Hello";

strtoupper( s, strlen( s ) );
```

Answer (score -3):

```
while (*string++ = toupper(*string));
```

Comment: The solution doesn't respect sequence points and leads to UB.

Comment: And even if it didn't, it wouldn't answer the question.

Comment: UB or not, that's difficult to read, which makes it error-prone. No need to code like this. I doubt this would pass a code review.

Comment: @RudiAngela Could you post a reference for this?

Comment: @RudiAngela The examples mentionned there all have two distinct variables which are accessed. In none of them one variable is used twice, as `string` in the example above. That is the essential difference here.

Comment: we could maintain two pointers here which always point to the same position, such as `while (*t++ = toupper(*s));` where `s` and `t` both point to the same location, but a mere `while (*string = toupper(*string)) string++;` is more intuitive here.

Comment: I take it intuition isn't what it used to be ;-)